# How to generate disk errors that are then repaired by Check Disk (chkdsk)

Tags: windows, hard-drive, chkdsk

I need to "break" things so that the Check Disk tool in Windows finds errors on a partition. Any ideas on how to do that in a controlled manner?

What can I do to make sure that chkdsk finds errors that it then fixes?

Comment: From [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)  "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. "

Comment: Wow. I think you are overdoing it. For me it is a valid question, with professional use. I teach people about technology. I have a lesson planned about disk errors and checking the disk for errors. Therefore, finding a way to generate such errors has practical real-life value. You should really back off!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to pull out the USB flash while the MS-Windows writes on it. The GUI-OS is in principle build so that the normal user action cannot produce FS error. You can do some errors form cmd, or on other non MS OS.

Comment: Good tips. Regarding the errors from cmd, can you point me to some documentation or tool that I can use? Thanks!

Comment: If I can you other non Microsoft OS to generate those errors, that's good too. Just give me a pointer or two. :)

Comment: The trick is to know the details of $MFT file, which is the main information source of NTFS filesystem. And to have powerfull tools to be able to change the bit structure of some record(s) of the $MFT file. Do not forget the NTFS makes a copy of $MFT called $MFTmirror (or somelike this), so you may need to make the changes in both to force the OS to start detail repair instead of silence restore the backuped data. Sorry I have not more time to deal with it now, I will spear some time over weekend. Meanwhile you may search WiKi for $MFT details, and Linux CLI commands `hexdump` and `dd`.